# Should I save keys of bundle in java constants or res/values/strings.xml or something else in android?

Tags: android

I have a lot of Intent to send message between activities and services in my APP.
Usually they will have some Object to pass by bundle.putString(key, someObject) and bundle.getString(key, someObject).

I want these keys to be well organized so I will be clear with messages being sent.As I think, they should be constants in Java, but for android, would it be better to put them in res/values/strings.xml named as key_xxx_xxx.

Thanks for any answers or comments.

Comment: "I think, they should be constants in Java". You code in java so you are on the right track.

Comment: better to use `Java Constants`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought about this matter a few days ago.

1. Use Java is better than strings.xml, like Android' s permissions are all Java `public static final` field. If you hava a lot of constants, you can also prepend a package name to be clear and identical, which strings.xml cannot supply.
2. If your xml file use the the key, I think is better to put the key in the strings.xml. For example, your `settings` xml file need a **string key**, and your java code also needs it, if you just put that key in java, you need to set text literal to the settings xml file, that may not good...

in short, it depends on the key used in java or xml or both.

hope it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to keep them as static constants. Make a java file as Utils.java and keep all the names there as Static Constants.

Something like this:

```
public static final String FIRST_KEY = "my_first_key";
```